# Virtualbox runs on OS without GUI

Tags: virtualbox

I have no experience with using Virtualbox. From what I understand virtualbox should run OS with GUI mode normally.

The problem is that when I run OS (Debian 32bit) it logs into console mode only. Virtualbox seems not to start X server. How can I enable GUI? Thanks.

I have enabled 3D acceleration and maxed out the video memory.

Comment: Is the ISO used a version of Debian with a GUI?

Comment: Others, who use the same image, run it with GUI

Comment: What happens when you try to run `startx` from a (guest) console?

Comment: it prints lots of error msgs like: "Illegal instruction at .." "xinit: giving up / unable to connect to X server connection refused / server error"

Comment: @tom Copy-paste the exact error message in /var/log/Xorg.0.log . And use capital letters and punctuations on your best. If you have a question about an *error*, then you should copy-paste the exact error message.

Answer (score 3):

Virtualbox doesn't usually control in what mode will the OS start, this option in linux generally is called RunLevel and you can control it via **`/etc/inittab`** .

If it usually boots in the console mode and you want to change it to GUI mode then you should first test if the system you have support GUI (technically having X11 installed) by typing **`init 5`** or **`startx`** in the command prompt...

If the GUI do start up then you should just change the default RunLevel in  `/etc/inittab` from *Level **3*** to *Level **5*** (as demonstrated in https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel), if not then GUI is not supported in the system installed and you will have 2 options:

1. **The hard way** : installing a GUI system
2. **The easy way** : re-installing the full version of the system (GUI included)

Comment: However, that won't work if just running `startx` runs into "xinit: giving up / unable to connect to X server connection refused / server error".  That's probably a configuration problem on the host.  But the OP has yet to post the exact error message...